# Which metrics are most useful in an ASP .Net build server?

Tags: asp.net, continuous-integration

I'm just wondering what metrics people measure on a build server.

I'm setting up a build server for a series of asp .net 2.0 projects.

On the server I'm currently measuring:

1. Unit test code coverage.
2. Build and test run time.
3. LOC (just out of idle curiosity).
4. Cyclomatic complexity.
5. Some FxCop rules.

What do you measure and how do you measure it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the benefit of (2) is, do you find it useful?

I certainly look at FxCop and StyleCop violation counts. In an ideal world these are 0, but on some projects this isn't realistic (e.g. inheriting legacy code), so we set a threshold and try not to exceed it.

Test coverage is good.

Sometimes it may be interesting to measure number of checkins and / or changed files since the last build. I never found an actual use for it but it was interesting to see how the rate of checkins increased towards the release date.

Comment: We test the build and test time (one value) as a way of seeing if there are any spikes. So if someone changes something, which still works, but adds a performance hit that is noticeable we pick it up that way.

Comment: ah, I see. That does sound useful.